# Add force to ball based on direction of camera

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-physics

I am attempting to create a minigolf game but am having trouble solving how to calculate the direction to hit the ball. I am thinking that it is easiest to hit the ball in the forward direction that the camera is facing, but I get unexpected results after the first hit as the ball will not calculate the correct direction after hitting the first time. How can I set the direction for hitting the ball and then apply the force I am calculating?

This is my script attached to my ball object at the moment. Sorry for the messiness.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Golfball : MonoBehaviour {
    public GameObject ball = null;
    public GameObject hole = null;
    public GameObject cam = null;
    public Text distance;
    public Text score;
    public Slider powerbar;
    private int strokes = 0;
    private bool isMoving = false;
    private bool increasing = true;
    private float distanceToHole;
    public float minHitPower = 40.0f;
    public float maxHitPower = 270.0f;
    private float hitPower = 0;
    private float powerIncrement = 5.0f;
    private float powerMultiplier = 10;
    private float ballRollTime = 0;
    private Vector3 ballDir;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start() {
        distance.GetComponent<Text>().text = "Distance To Hole:" + distanceToHole;
        ball.GetComponent<Rigidbody> ();
        score.GetComponent<Text>().text = "Strokes:" + strokes;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        //Allow the ball to be hit if the ball is not null, not currently moving, and the left mouse button is clicked.
        if (ball != null) {

            if (Input.GetButton("Fire1") && !isMoving) {
                calculatePower ();
            }

            //Hit ball using power level and set ball to moving.
            if (Input.GetButtonUp("Fire1"))
            {/**********************************************
                //Calculate direction to hit ball
                ballDir = cam.transform.forward.normalized;
                hitBall(hitPower);
                isMoving = true;
            }**********************************************/

            //Detect when the ball stops
            if (isMoving) {
                ballRollTime += Time.deltaTime;
                if (ballRollTime > 1 && GetComponent<Rigidbody> ().velocity.magnitude <= 0.5) {
                    GetComponent<Rigidbody> ().velocity = Vector3.zero;
                    GetComponent<Rigidbody> ().angularVelocity = Vector3.zero;
                    isMoving = false;
                }
            } else {
                ballRollTime = 0;
            }
        }
        //Calculate distance to hole
        distanceToHole = Mathf.Round((Vector3.Distance(ball.transform.position, hole.transform.position) * 100f) / 100f);
        distance.GetComponent<Text>().text = "Distance To Hole: " + distanceToHole;

        Debug.DrawLine(ball.transform.position, ballDir, Color.red, Mathf.Infinity);
    }

    void calculatePower(){
        //Increase power if it is less than the max power.
        if (increasing)
        {
            if (hitPower < maxHitPower)
            {
                hitPower += powerIncrement * powerMultiplier;
                increasing = true;
            }
            else if (hitPower >= maxHitPower)
            {
                increasing = false;
            }
        }
        //Decrease power if power level is not increasing until the power hits the minimum level.
        if(!increasing) {
            //Debug.Log ("Not Increasing");
            if (hitPower > minHitPower) {
                //Debug.Log ("HitPower: " + hitPower);
                hitPower -= powerIncrement * powerMultiplier;
            } else if (hitPower <= minHitPower) {
                increasing = true;
            }
        }
        //Update the slider
        powerbar.value = hitPower / powerMultiplier;
    }

    void hitBall (float power){

        //Add force to the ball
        //ball.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce(new Vector3(0, 0, power));
        //Camera.main.transform.forward
        ball.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddRelativeForce(ballDir * power);

        //Increase stroke count
        strokes++;
        updateScore(strokes);

        //Reset the power  and power bar level to minimum default after hitting ball
        hitPower = minHitPower;
        powerbar.value = hitPower / powerMultiplier;
        Debug.Log("HitPower Reset: " + hitPower);
    }

    void updateScore(int stroke)
    {
        score.GetComponent<Text>().text = "Strokes:" + stroke;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to apply the force like that:

```
ball.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce(ballDir * power, ForceMode.Impulse);
```

But you'll probably have to play with your 'power' variable.
Also note that you want to use impulse because you are hitting the ball and not applying force for some period of time.

The `ballDir * power` multiples the ballDir vector by your float number. You probably already know how it works, but here is the rundown:

```
scalarValue * new Vector(x0, x1, ..., xn) == new Vector(scalarValue * x0, scalarValue * x1, ... scalarValue * xn);]
```

You might also want to get rid of direction's `y` component so that your ball doesn't fly into the air (you are playing minigolf, right?)

```
ballDir.y = 0;
```

Comment: OP: What Mokona mentioned, and (I see that you commented that part of code out) make sure ballDir is set to the camera's forward direction. If you ask me, I'd just use the camera's vector directly in the force assignment, as ballDir could accidentally be changed elsewhere.

Comment: I actually figured out the problem. My ball object's x and z axis were rotating with the object when it was hit, and thus when I would hit the first time the rotation values for the ball transform were 0, 0, 0. After hitting, these rotation values oriented the ball much differently and so the ball would be hit toward the camera based on the new direction the Z axis was pointing. I disabled rotation to fix the problem and now everything works as intended. I can add images to show what I mean later.